# Do I have to call all the code blocks in org-mode to chain them?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

Imagine this org file

```
#+NAME: get-referral-code-payload
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir ~/Developer/data :results raw :exports code
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@userData.json" -X POST https://api.staging.fake.com/referral
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: get-referral-code-payload
{"referral_code":"tom59","zip":"94000","state":"CA","city":"SF"}

#+NAME: parse-referral-code
#+BEGIN_SRC js :var payload=get-referral-code-payload 
let parsedPayload = JSON.parse(payload);
return parsedPayload.access_token;
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: parse-referral-code
```

Whenever I try to run the second code block Spacemacs asks me if I want to run the previous blocks (I have several IRL) which is fine, in case I would like to refresh the values, but if I don't run them, the `:var` is undefined even though the `#+RESULTS: get-referral-code-payload` clearly has a value.

Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: But `get-access-token-payload` is a different beast: where does *it* come from?

Comment: It was a typo, good catch. The chain of scripts is long and I got it wrong, thanks @NickD.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`:cache` header argument](https://orgmode.org/manual/cache.html). You can avoid repeated source block evaluation with it. That is okay if your source blocks do not have side-effects, i.e., if their arguments determine their results.